# Adding a polygon on Mapbox map in Angular 9

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, angular9

I'm using `mapbox-gl` to add a Mapbox map to my Angular app, that works so far. The approach is very similar to this one [here](https://codepen.io/cansadadeserfeliz/pen/JKmRbQ) but I'm unable to find `Polygon` in the Angular port of that library.

Here's my component code:

```
private mapElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('map', { static: false }) set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if (content) { // initially setter gets called with undefined
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(mapboxgl, "accessToken").set(this.mapBoxKey);
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: content.nativeElement,
            style: this.globals.MapboxStyle,
            zoom: 12,
            center: [this.centerLng, this.centerLat]
        });

        // Add map controls
        this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

        //at this point I'd like to add a polygon....

    }
}
```

`map.addLayer` seems to accept a first argument of type `Layer` but I'm not sure where to find this type and I'm not able to create an instance of it.

Am I missing a package here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how I ended up doing it. Apparently, there are no types included in the Angular port of Mapbox-GL library, so you have to use generic objects.

```js
private mapElement: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('map', { static: false }) set content(content: ElementRef) {
    if (content) { // initially setter gets called with undefined

        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(mapboxgl, "accessToken").set(this.mapBoxKey);
        this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: content.nativeElement,
            style: this.globals.MapboxStyle,
            zoom: 12,
            center: [this.centerLng, this.centerLat]
        });

        // Add map controls
        this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

        let me = this;
        me.space = this.space

        this.map.on('load', function (e) {
            this.addSource('space', { type: "geojson", data: me.space.geometry });
            this.addLayer({
                'id': 'space',
                'type': 'fill',
                'source': 'space',
                'layout': {},
                'paint': {
                    'fill-color': '#088',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.8
                }
           });
      });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just using the standard Mapbox-GL-JS API. The documentation is here: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api

The example you linked is using mapbox.js, not Mapbox-GL-JS. That's a completely separate library.

Comment: Correct, I think I have to do it through a geojson: https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/?